# List limited items and search from full items in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am displaying a list of 5 items from 50 items.User able to search from entire list(from 50items) but not from only 5 items.How can I implement this on angluarJs.
I am following this method because I want to reduce ajax requrest.

angularJs code is,

```
       <div class="txt">
                    <a href="{{mall.link}}" ng-repeat="mall in malls|limitTo:2| filter:searchMall" title="{{mall.name}}"><img src="{{mall.image_url}}"/></a>
                    <a class="more" href="#">More &gt;</a>
                </div>
    app.controller('mallController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.malls =
                    [
                        {name: 'mall1', image_url: 'assets/images/malls/1.png', link: "/#mall1"},
                        {name: 'mall2', image_url: 'assets/images/malls/2.png', link: "/#mall2"},
                   ...
                   ...
                  50 rows

         ];
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to limit the number of the items shown by using `ng-if` like this:

```
<a href="{{mall.link}}" 
   ng-repeat="mall in malls|filter:searchMall" 
   ng-if="$index < 6"
   title="{{mall.name}}">
    <img src="{{mall.image_url}}"/>
</a>
```